# Production alternative for Hyperledger Cryptogen

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have tested and understood how a hyperledger network works from this tutorial https://github.com/leadiq/heroes-service. Now I am starting thinking a production env. Which tool should I use to replace bin/cryptogen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Hyperledger Fabric Certificate Authority](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/) to issue the required cryptographic material or you can use any certificate authority software which can issue EC certificates